# What is a normal subgroup generated by all nth powers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

In a definition I am looking at (Burnside groups) it mentions the normal subgroup of a free group $F_{m}$ generated by all $n^{th}$ powers of the elements of $F_{m}$.
I roughly understand this but I don't know whether it means $\langle a^{n}, b^{n}, ... \rangle$ or $\langle a^{1},a^{2},..., a^{n}, b^{1}, ..., b^{n},... \rangle$.
I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: It mean the normal (in fact characteristic) subgroup $\langle g^n : g  \in F_n \rangle$.

Comment: Generated by all possible $n$-th powers (but not $m$-th powers for $m\neq n$).

Comment: Thankyou very much - I get it now :)

Comment: @ZoeMitchell Are you sure that here the index $n$ of $F_n$ coincides with the powers, also $n$-th powers? Isn't it $F_m^n=\langle g^n\mid g\in F_m\rangle$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a problem with the notation. The subgroup considered is, I think, the subgroup $F_2^n$ of $F_2=\langle a,b\rangle$ generated by all $n$-th powers of elements of $F_2$. If you consider the free group with more than $2$ generators, it should have a different index, say $F_m$. Then the subgroup is denoted by $F_m^n$.

Comment: I believe you are right - this typo caused me a lot of wasted mental effort but thank you very much for pointing it out :)